# 'editable-field' widget is not playing nice with `widget-value-set'

Tags: widget

When I evaluate the following form,

```
(defun magithub-issue-form ()
  (interactive)
  (with-current-buffer (generate-new-buffer "*magithub issue*")
    (switch-to-buffer-other-window (current-buffer))
    (widget-value-set (widget-create 'editable-field
                                     :tag "Title"
                                     :format "%t: %v\n\n"
                                     :size 76)
                      "Some default title")
    (use-local-map widget-keymap)
    (widget-setup)))
```

I get a buffer that looks like this:

```
Title: Some default title<editable field starts here>
```

`widget-value-set` works for other widget types (like `checklist`), so why does it misbehave for `editable-field`?

---

A similar issue is happening for widget type `text`:

[image: example]